# Add data using migration Entity Framework Core without specifying the id

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to use EF migrations to add some data inside my DB. The fact is that all Id are auto-generated. I found the standard way to achieve it with EF Core, which is the following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeNote>()
    .HasData(
    new TypeNote { Id = 1, Name = "General" },
    new TypeNote { Id = 2, Name = "E-mail" },
    new TypeNote { Id = 3, Name = "Meeting" },
    new TypeNote { Id = 4, Name = "Reminder" },
    new TypeNote { Id = 5, Name = "Telephone" },
    new TypeNote { Id = 6, Name = "Visit" }
);
```

My issue here is that I don't want to specify the `Id`, but it seems that there is no other way using `HasData` method.

Do you know another way to add data inside DB using migration?

Comment: What happens if you remove `Id = x` from all the lines

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found a way to do an insert during migration:

```
        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "TypeNote",
            columns: new[] { "Name" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
                { "Test" },
                { "Test1" }
        });
```

The fact is that I wanted to access dbContext inside the migration. Which is impossible because DB is updating.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID of the inserted row and use it in another `InsertData` method?

Answer (score 5):

First I created an empty migration naming it like `PopulatingTableX`.
Then I did add the data insertion like this (EF 6) in the `Up` method:

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData("Status",
           columns: new[] { nameof(StatusEntity.Entity), nameof(StatusEntity.Name), nameof(StatusEntity.CreationDate), nameof(StatusEntity.IsActive) },
           values: new object[,] {
                   { "Branch", "Active", DateTime.UtcNow, true },
                   { "Branch", "Closed", DateTime.UtcNow, true },
                   { "Branch", "Openning", DateTime.UtcNow, true },
                   { "Branch", "Closing", DateTime.UtcNow, true }
           }
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard for **HasData**. Auto generated fields are not generated with **HasData** method.

Please have a look at this [EntityFrameworkCore issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11776).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is referred to as "seed data"

Please check out this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) on how to add seed data to your database and let me know whether or not that is what you're looking for.